# Register service as self, but as an implementation of another class/service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

(Edited)

I'm sorry for the confusing title, but I'm not sure how to formulate myself. I'll just dive into it!

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IEntityService<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task<T> GetAsync(string id);
    Task CreateAsync(T entity);
}

public interface IEntityGetAllService<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();
}
```

I also have a class that implements both these interfaces:

```
public class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T>, IEntityGetAllService<T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository<T> _entityRepository;

    public EntityService(IEntityRepository<T> entityRepository)
    {
        _entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(string id)
    {
        return await _entityRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _entityRepository.Create(entity);
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _entityRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Now, I create the following service:

```
public class FooService : IEntityService<Foo>
{
    private readonly IEntityService<Foo> _entityService;

    public EntityService(IEntityService<Foo> entityService)
    {
        _entityService = entityService;
    }

    public Task<Foo> GetAsync(string id)
    {
        return _entityService.GetAsync(id);
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(Foo entity)
    {
        _entityService.CreateAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

Then I can register `FooService` as itself. However, one could argue that I could just inject `IEntityService<Foo>` instead, but that would allow the use of `GetAllAsync` for the `Foo` entity, which should not be allowed. Therefore, I want to control what methods to allow, by implementing each interface in the `FooService`. For example, `BarService` could implement both `IEntityService<Bar>` and `IEntityGetAllService<Bar>`, which would allow all methods for the `BarService`. The problem here is that each service would do exactly the same, implement IEntityService and perform the exact same methods, but for different entities. Can I automatically register each service to use the implementation of `EntityService<>`?

Is this even possible? I've tried several methods, using abstract classes, assembly scanning, manual registration etc., but I can't for the sake of my life understand how to achieve this, if it even is possible.

Comment: You can't inject `BoatService` as is...it's abstract.

Comment: So your question is just how to do that? Have you looked at the autofac docs?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you'd like to achieve. Could you update your question and show in plain C# what the resulting structure of created objects should look like?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I've tried to improve my question!

Comment: I would recommend [AutoRegisterDI](https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi) lib. It's fast, simple and based on Microsoft Dependency Injection. This [benchmark](https://ipjohnson.github.io/DotNet.DependencyInjectionBenchmarks/) will show you the speed difference. And this is the [article](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-fast-and-automatic-dependency-injection-setup/) about how to use it.